# Saving results in the new file everytime I rerun the python code (the name should include the date that a user is choosing as an input)

Tags: python, csv, date, filenames, oserror

few parts of the code:

```py
def daysList(adate) :

    from datetime import date, timedelta

    from_y = int(adate[0][0:4])
    from_m = int(adate[0][4:6])
    from_d = int(adate[0][6:])

    to_y  = int(adate[1][0:4])
    to_m  = int(adate[1][4:6])
    to_d  = int(adate[1][6:])

    to_date = date(to_y,to_m,to_d)
    from_date = date(from_y,from_m,from_d)

    days = (to_date-from_date).days

    dateList = []
    for d in range(0,days+1) :
        n_date = str(from_date + timedelta(days=d))
        dateList.append(n_date.split("-"))

    return dateList

outfile = f'Stations{daysList}.csv'

with open(options.outfile, 'w') as ofile:
    for row in DB:
        ofile.write('%s\n' % ','.join(row))
```

The error that I am getting:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Stations<function daysList at 0x000001F4E4BBC430>.csv'
```

Comment: You need to call `daysList` with whatever adate is supposed to be - `outfile = f'Stations{daysList(adate)}.csv'`

Comment: to run the code I use: python retrieveInterMagnet.py -s HYB:HON:BOU:EBR -d '10/010/2019'     and that date at the end is changeable. What I need to get is a file name with the correct date that was used to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you open (create) a file you must pass a string as filename.
However, the variable outfile that contains such variable is not correctly formed because dayslist does not seems to be directly printable.
I suggest you to write it this way:

```
days = daysList(adate)
start = days[0]
end = days[-1]
outfile = f'Stations{start}-{end}.csv'
```

If you prefer you can write it inline:

```
outfile = f'Stations{days[0]}-{days[-1]}.csv'
```

Comment: `daysList` is a function, not an array-like.

Comment: sorry, I meant forget to add parentheses with the argument

Comment: since both the   outfile    and     start/end     are parts of different functions, the code does not allow me to use anything other than the fuction - daysList

Comment: you can use the function daysList, but you should use it properly: you should first call it somewhere and store the returned list in a variable (see my answer).
Then you should use the values contained in that variable to properly construct the string of filename

Answer (score 0):

Note that in this line:

```
outfile = f'Stations{daysList}.csv'
```

You're not using the output of daysList for some argument; you're using daysList itself, the function. The code you've provided is incomplete (What is `options`? What do you intend to pass as an argument to daysList?) but I'd start there.

Comment: parser.set_defaults(verbose=True, input='List.csv', stations=None, odate=None, email="blablabla@gmail.com", outfile = f'Stations{daysList}.csv')

Comment: @KejtMazur – where is the user input that you mentioned that the user is choosing? The argument that you wish to pass into `daysList`?

Comment: python retrieveInterMagnet.py -s HYB:HON:BOU:EBR -d '10/010/2019' <-here, the date, the code is downloading files from the web page for the chosen date.

Comment: So it is a command line argument; in that case, you should obtain the date from the user (by the .set_defaults, I assume you're using the argparse module. Look into how you get values using argparse), and only once you have that, you can set outfile=f'Stations{daysList(userInputDate)}' (where userInputDate can be wherever you store it). In other words: if you want your default file name to depend on user input, then you have to obtain the user input before setting the default file name.